# Invalid response line returned from server: HTTP/2 200 - message after update to 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1.7

I seem to be getting this message after i updated to Magento 2.1.7 - it only displays on the contact page when someone submits the form.

Invalid response line returned from server: `HTTP/2 200`

**I see this in the magento log file:**

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php
>   on line 83 [] []

Comment: Have you check magento log file?

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck in Magento 2.3.3 extension manager and just replaced

```
!2 with <2
```

and it worked.