# How to add Preference for Magento/Framework files?

Tags: magento2.2.6

I am using curl and it is working fine in local..but returning

```
Invalid response line returned from server: HTTP/2 200
```

in live server.

I referred this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251348/invalid-response-line-returned-from-server-http-2-200-message-after-update-to)

How to add preference or plugin to overwrite parseHeaders function in  `vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try making like this:

In custom modules di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock"    type="YourCompany\YourModule\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock" />
<  /config>
```

Create your overide file in your custom module.

Comment: Tried preference like this. But it didn't work.